# Excel formula to make Combinations using =MAKEARRAY

Tags: excel, combinations, permutation

I want to use the forumla =makearray() to create an array of all possible combinations of numbers.

Variables are N,R

Population would be {1,2,3,..N-1,N}
Set would be {1,2,3...R-1,R}

Number of Array Rows - combin(N,R)

Number of Array Columns - R

Example Result 1: N=5,R=3

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |

Example Result 2: N=6,R=4

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I have been trying for a few days. I am able to create a permutations function, but I can't get one that is selective of order and repetition.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily restrict myself to solutions which use `MAKEARRAY`. This problem has been discussed [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/efficient-approach-to-generate-list-of-combinations-with-no/m-p/3786730) quite recently.